# Message Box unable to call local variable

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, messagebox

I'm going to preface this by saying I'm sure the question has already been asked but I've tried all the suggestions and nothing seems to work for me. It just keeps returning a blank message box. If the answer were just a nice snippet of code I can add to my answer that would be fantastic.

```
        private string Text1;
    public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txtbx = new TextBox();
        txtbx.Height = 50;
        txtbx.Width = 200;
        txtbx.Margin = new Thickness(771, 282, 0, 0);
        txtbx.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        txtbx.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        Text1 = txtbx.Text;

        if (EditChecked == true)
        {
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(txtbx);
            Button Save = new Button();
            Save.Height = 25;
            Save.Width = 50;
            Save.Content = "Save";
            Save.Margin = new Thickness(771, 382, 0, 0);
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(Save);
            txtbx.Text = Text1;
            Save.Click += delegate
            {
                txtbx.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                Save.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            };
        }
        else if (ViewChecked == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Text1);
        }

    }
```

Edit: Thanks to mjwills I moved the "Text1 = txtbx.Text;" line so this is what ended up working fyi:

```
        private string Text1;
        public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txtbx = new TextBox();
        txtbx.Height = 50;
        txtbx.Width = 200;
        txtbx.Margin = new Thickness(771, 282, 0, 0);
        txtbx.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        txtbx.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);


        if (EditChecked == true)
        {
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(txtbx);
            Button Save = new Button();
            Save.Height = 25;
            Save.Width = 50;
            Save.Content = "Save";
            Save.Margin = new Thickness(771, 382, 0, 0);
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(Save);
            txtbx.Text = Text1;
            Save.Click += delegate
            {
                txtbx.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                Save.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                Text1 = txtbx.Text;
            };
        }
```

Comment: Given that `txtbx.Text` is blank, why are you expecting anything other than a blank message box?

Comment: Did the behaviour change if you commented out `Text1 = txtbx.Text;`?

Comment: Do you realize this code makes a _new_ text box and button every time you click the button it is linked to? Maybe you should put these elements on the design and just make them start out as invisible...

Comment: Side notes: 1) Don't use `== true` to check booleans. The thing you are checking _is already a boolean_; adding `== true` will not make it any more a boolean than it already is. 2) Private variables like that `string Text1` should not start with a capital letter. In C#, only class names, functions and properties should start with a capital letter.

Comment: @mjwills someone enters text into it after it appears// no

Comment: @Nyer, yes, ig you could do that too.

Comment: @Christheyankee `someone enters text into it after it appears` No they don't. `MessageBox.Show(Text1);` runs **before** they have a chance to type something in. Step through it with the debugger and see for yourself. Also read Nyerguds comment above.

Comment: You declare a privat Variable Text1. You create a new TextBox. Never put it on the UI. Then assign it's text (wich should be a empty string) to Text1. And then wonder that MessageBox(Text1) is a empty string? Nothing in your code makes sense. You create new UI Elements, but never actually display them. And even if you did, the user can not enter anything while your Click Handler runs. Whatever your goal was, you have to be at least a Lightyear away from it with this code. Go 3 steps back.

Comment: @Christopher the text box is added to the UI in the `LayoutRoot.Children.Add(txtbx)` line... but that's only executed if `EditChecked` is true. But, yes, the code doesn't make much sense.

Comment: If you want user Input: 1. Place a Textbox in the Designer. 2. Give it a name (that is the variable name you can access it under later in code). 3. Extract the value the user has inputted and use it. | As advanced option you might be able to use something like a Input Dialog.

Comment: @Christopher I would, but our instructor doesn't want the textbox visible until the user executes something so I'm using a click event.

Comment: @Nyerguds That's cause its tailored to what my teacher is requiring

Comment: @mjwills Are you saying that it gets the text from the textbox too early or executes the message box to early??? Because  the message box only displays when the "view" radio button is selected.

Comment: @ Everyone guys I'm just trying to get an A so help within whats up there would be appreciated, I'm sure its a simple fix.

Comment: @ Everyone never mind I figured it out, mjwills was right.

Answer (score 0):

You declare:

```
private string Text1;
```

However you only assign it on the chance:

```
EditChecked = True
```

And you only display the message if

```
EditChecked = False
```

So, you need to assign Text1 on if the EditChecked = False. Perhaps on the declaration:

```
private string Text1 = "My default message";
```

Comment: I actually found another way to do it, but thnx.